# Regex For Strings in C

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm looking to make a regular expression for some strings in C.

This is what i have so far:

Strings in C are delimited by double quotes (") so the regex has to be surrounded by \" \".

The string may not contain newline characters so I need to do [^\n] ( I think ).

The string may also contain double quotes or back slash characters if and only if they're escaped. Therefore [\\ \"] (again I think).

Other than that anything else goes.

Any help is much appreciated I'm kind of lost on how to start writing this regex.

Comment: Are you trying to match all strings without newline characters that may or may not have escaped back slashes and escaped double quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for a string literal in flex/lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039795/regular-expression-for-a-string-literal-in-flex-lex)

Comment: Yes that is correct @ N Brown

Comment: @Ken Y-N that posts asks a similar question but none of the answer complete the question as it still allows for a newline character.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9260547/1270789) specifically says it is for single lines.

Comment: If you used that regex it would allow for the input of "\n" to where it should throw a Lexical Error.

Comment: So adapt it and exclude `\n`? Also, do you need to handle trigraphs?

Comment: @keny-n: that's what the answer claims but it is wrong, notwithstanding the upvotes. As melpomene says, you just have to add `\n` to the character class of exclusions.

Answer (score 5):

A simple flex pattern to recognize string literals (including literals with embedded line continuations):

```
["]([^"\\\n]|\\.|\\\n)*["]
```

That will allow

```
   "string with \
line continuation"
```

But not

```
"C doesn't support
 multiline strings"
```

If you don't want to deal with line continuations, remove the `\\\n` alternative. If you need trigraph support, it gets more irritating.

Although that *recognizes* strings, it doesn't attempt to make sense of them. Normally, a C lexer will want to process strings with backslash sequences, so that `"\"\n"` is converted to the two characters <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>NL</kbd> (`0x22 0x0A`). You might, at some point, want to take a look at, for example, [Optimizing flex string literal parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354725/optimizing-flex-string-literal-parsing/42358417) (although that will need to be adapted if you are programming in C).

Flex patterns are documented in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html). It might also be worthwhile reading a good reference on regular expressions, such as John Levine's excellent book on [Flex and Bison](https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=nYUkAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).